# Como referirse a un parámetro de variable desde dentro de una función

Tags: javascript

os planteo mi problema.
Estoy haciendo un ejercicio basado en la creación de un programa que calcula si un número insertado por un **`prompt`** pedido al usuario es **Armstrong** o no. Necesito hacerlo con una función, pero antes de hacerla cree el código y comprobé que era correcto.
El resultado es el siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me devuelve lo siguiente: 
El número introducido es el 231.
El primer número lo eleva a la longitud total del dígito introducido, en éste caso 3. Con el segundo hace igual o con el tercero, lo mismo.
La última línea corresponde a la suma de los resultado del haber elevado anteriormente los números a 3.
En éste caso 36 por lo que **NO** sería un número Armstrong.

Lo único que me falta es que vuelva la frase de mi función que escribe = "Esto no es un número Armstrong", pero no consigo hacer una referencia al valor introducido desde dentro de la función.

A continuación mi código:

```
var input = prompt("Input a number of three digits");
var result = armstrong(input);
function armstrong (input){
    var str = input;
    var res = str.substr(0, 1);
    var res2 = str.substr(1, 1);
    var res3 = str.substr(2, 1);
    var op = res ** 3;
    var op2 = res2 ** 3;
    var op3 = res3 ** 3;
    var opp = op + op2 + op3;
    document.write(res + " **3 = " + op + "<br/>");
    document.write(res2 + " **3 = " + op2 + "<br/>");
    document.write(res3 + " **3 = " + op3 + "<br/>");
    document.write(opp + "<br/>");

        if (opp == input) {//punto de mi problema. 
            return ("This is an Armstrong number");
        } else {
            return ("Not an Armstrong number");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En teoría solo tienes que imprimir el resultado, esta realizando el return pero no lo estas mostrando.

```js
var input = prompt("Input a number of three digits");
var result = armstrong(input);
document.write(result);
function armstrong (input){
    var str = input;
    var res = str.substr(0, 1);
    var res2 = str.substr(1, 1);
    var res3 = str.substr(2, 1);
    var op = res ** 3;
    var op2 = res2 ** 3;
    var op3 = res3 ** 3;
    var opp = op + op2 + op3;
    document.write(res + " **3 = " + op + "<br/>");
    document.write(res2 + " **3 = " + op2 + "<br/>");
    document.write(res3 + " **3 = " + op3 + "<br/>");
    document.write(opp + "<br/>");

        if (opp == input) {//punto de mi problema. 
            return ("This is an Armstrong number");
        } else {
            return ("Not an Armstrong number");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya lo vi, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente estás guardando el resultado de la función en una variable.

Deberías de imprimir esa variable por pantalla, ya sea mediante `alert(result)` o `console.log(result)` (ten en cuenta que este último se muestra en el snippet de Stackoverflow pero que no será visible en un navegador, solamente si abres la consola) o insertándola en cualquier elemento del DOM.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```js
var input = prompt("Input a number of three digits");
var result = armstrong(input);
function armstrong (input){
    var str = input;
    var res = str.substr(0, 1);
    var res2 = str.substr(1, 1);
    var res3 = str.substr(2, 1);
    var op = res ** 3;
    var op2 = res2 ** 3;
    var op3 = res3 ** 3;
    var opp = op + op2 + op3;
    document.write(res + " **3 = " + op + "<br/>");
    document.write(res2 + " **3 = " + op2 + "<br/>");
    document.write(res3 + " **3 = " + op3 + "<br/>");
    document.write(opp + "<br/>");

        if (opp == input) {//punto de mi problema. 
            return ("This is an Armstrong number");
        } else {
            return ("Not an Armstrong number");
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Así de fácil y no fui capaz de verlo, vaya...

Comment: @KelvinMacay A veces los errores más simples son los que llevan unos quebraderos de cabeza mayores. Seguro que para la próxima lo ves a la primera :P

Answer (score 1):

Guardas el valor, de lo que *retorna* tu función, pero **NO** lo usas, solo bastaría con hacer algo como:

```
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Además te dejaré un código más pequeñito que te he realizado para *el mismo fin* del número armstrong

```js
function armstrong (s){
  var cube = null,
      result = s.split("").forEach(numero => {
      cube += Math.pow(parseInt(numero), s.toString().length);
  });
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = cube === parseInt(s) && s > 0 ? "Es número armstrong" : "No es número armstrong";
}

var input = document.getElementById("arm");

input.addEventListener("keyup", e => {armstrong(input.value)});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="arm" placeHolder="Armstrong">
<i id=result></i>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias.